# p:selectOneMenu hide popup on mouseOut event

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsf, primefaces

I have a PrimeFaces component, and I need to hide popup of its element on mouseOut event. But I can`t add onmouseout in component, because PrimeFaces does not support this attribute.

```
<p:selectCheckboxMenu id="selectCheckboxMenu" label="selectCheckboxMenu" onmouseout="hidePopup">
  <f:selectItems value="#{SelectOneMenuBean.availableRegions}" />
</p:selectCheckboxMenu>
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Be careful with adding [tag:javascript] and [tag:jquery] to jsf or more specific PrimeFaces questions. You'll get responses of people who just know both these technologies but **not** in the context of PrimeFaces. Many answer will not be applicable then (== 'usable/good') , even when upvoted (by other javascript/jquery users)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have mentioned `jquery` you can add [**`mouseout`**](https://api.jquery.com/mouseout/) as below:

```
$("#selectCheckboxMenu").on('mouseout',function(){
   //write hidePopup function content here
});
```

Or you can also try [**`mouseleave`**](https://api.jquery.com/mouseleave/)

```
$("#selectCheckboxMenu").on('mouseleave',function(){
   //write hidePopup function content here
});
```

Comment: Do you use JSF? Or in this case PrimeFaces? I tried to apply your answer to the PrimeFaces ShowCase of the selectCheckboxMenu and it failed (replaced `#selectCheckboxMenu` with `#j_idt87:\\menu`. I put just an alert in function and it fires way to often

Comment: Thank you, this is very interesting solution. I solved my problem using another way, but you solution really safe my day.

Comment: Glad it helped! anyways happy coding.. :)